# Load image event with jQuery fails in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm struggling with loading an image for my popup in Internet Explorer 8, and I don't know why it returns "Image failed to load." all the time.

I first thought it was a caching problem, but it wasn't it seems, so now I don't know what it is...

```
    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imageSource)
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            $("#imagePopup .content").html('Image failed to load.');
        }
        else {
            $("#imagePopup .content").html(img);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
var img = $('<img/>').load(function() {
   // Loading done ..
   img.appendTo("#imagePopup .content");
}).error(function(){
   // Unable to load image ..
   $("#imagePopup .content").html('Image failed to load.');
}).attr('src', imageSource);
```

Comment: That partly worked fine but it seems that IE8 needs full url path to load image? if i supply it with full url like mydomain.com/image/1.jpg it works great but if i supply it with just /image/1.jpg it just keeps loading image.

Comment: No it doesn't :/ IE8 is weird

Comment: Now after it worked with your function the famous IE8 caching problem kicked in :) Math.random()*99999 did the trick. thanks

Comment: Well.. actually you could just use a timestamp as for example "imageURL+'?i='+(new Date().getTime());"

Comment: I also have the same problem. It is a silent issue and my loading keeps working :-( anyone can help give a good example here. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

naturlwidth is not supported in IE8. You would have to use the height and width property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Always good to know for future reference.

Comment: Sure it doesn't support naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties.